# Add custom field to Spark ML LabeldPoint

Tags: java, machine-learning, apache-spark

How can I add some custom field(i.e user id) to predictions result?

```
        List<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint> localTesting = ... ;//
        // I want to add some identifier to each LabeledPoint

        DataFrame localTestDF = jsql.createDataFrame(jsc.parallelize(studyData.localTesting), LabeledPoint.class);
        DataFrame predictions = model.transform(localTestDF);
        Row[] collect = predictions.select("label", "probability", "prediction").collect();
        for (Row r : collect) {
            // and want to return identifier here.
            // so do I save I to database.
            int userNo = Integer.parseInt(r.get(0).toString());
            double prob = Double.parseDouble(r.get(1).toString());
            int prediction = Integer.parseInt(r.get(2).toString());
            log.debug(userNo + "," + prob + ", " + prediction);
        }
```

but when I used this class for localTesting instead of LabeledPoint,

```
class NoLabeledPoint extends LabeledPoint implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2488661810406135403L;
    int userNo;
    public NoLabeledPoint(double label, Vector features) {
        super(label, features);
    }

    public int getUserNo() {
        return userNo;
    }

    public void setUserNo(int userNo) {
        this.userNo = userNo;
    }
}

        List<NoLabeledPoint> localTesting = ... ;// set every user'no to the field userNo
        // I want to add some identifier to each LabeledPoint

        DataFrame localTestDF = jsql.createDataFrame(jsc.parallelize(studyData.localTesting), LabeledPoint.class);
        DataFrame predictions = model.transform(localTestDF);
        Row[] collect = predictions.select("userNo", "probability", "prediction").collect();
        for (Row r : collect) {
            // and want to return identifier here.
            // so do I save I to database.
            int userNo = Integer.parseInt(r.get(0).toString());
            double prob = Double.parseDouble(r.get(1).toString());
            int prediction = Integer.parseInt(r.get(2).toString());
            log.debug(userNo + "," + prob + ", " + prediction);
        }
```

exception has thrown

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'userNo' given input columns rawPrediction, probability, features, label, prediction;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:51)
```

I mean I want to get not only prediction data(feature, label, probability..) but also some custom field I want. for example userNo, user_id and so on
from the result : predictions.select("...... ")

**update**

solved. one line should be fixed

from

```
            DataFrame localTestDF = jsql.createDataFrame(jsc.parallelize(studyData.localTesting), LabeledPoint.class);
```

to

```
            DataFrame localTestDF = jsql.createDataFrame(jsc.parallelize(studyData.localTesting), NoLabeledPoint.class);
```

Comment: I have yet to find a reliable way to do this. As of right now, I have stored relevant metadata in the `label` object for my validation subset by hacking it to look like a float (in my example, it looks like `datetime.primary_key`, e.g `150101.12345` for January 1st, 2015, primary key 12345). As far as I can tell, there is no built in system for storing metadata about `LabeledPoint` objects.

Comment: Can we try the .zip function in RDD https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#zip(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag) and map it with the userId, actualLabel and predictedLabel. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-decision-tree.html Also, the Java example uses plain map to join with predictions. The zip function assumes that the two RDDs have the *same number of partitions* and the *same number of elements in each partition* (e.g. one was made through a map on the other).

Comment: @AnchitChoudhry no way with spark.ml ? (RDD use high level functionality, so no deals with RDDS directly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't use low level MLlib API there is no need to use `LabeledPoint` at all. After you create a `DataFrame` all you get is simply a `Row` with certain values, and all that matters* is types and column names matching the parameters in your pipeline.

In Scala you can use any case class

```scala
org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector; case class 

case class LabeledPointWithMeta(userNo: String, label: Double, features: Vector)

val rdd: RDD[LabeledPointWithMeta] = ???
val df = rdd.toDF
```

To be able to use it from you should probably add `@BeanInfo` annotation:

```
import scala.beans.BeanInfo

@BeanInfo
case class LabeledPointWithMeta(...)
```

Based on a [Spark SQL and DataFrame Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection) it looks like in plain Java you can do something like this**:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;

public static class LabeledPointWithMeta implements Serializable {
  private int userNo;
  private double label;
  private Vector vector;

  public int getUserNo() {
    return userNo;
  }

  public void setUserNo(int userNo) {
    this.userNo = userNo;
  }

  public double getLabel() {
    return label;
  }

  public void setLabel(double label) {
    this.label = label;
  }

  public Vector getVector() {
    return vector;
  }

  public void seVector(Vector vector) {
    this.vector = vector;
  }

}
```

and after that:

```
JavaRDD<LabeledPointWithMeta> myPoints = ...;

DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myPoints LabeledPointWithMeta.class);
```

I think a simple change in your code should work as well:

```
DataFrame localTestDF = jsql.createDataFrame(
    jsc.parallelize(studyData.localTesting),
    NoLabeledPoint.class
);
```

It won't help you if you want to use MLlib, but this part can be easily handled with simple `RDD` transformations like `zip`.

---

* Some metadata to, but you won't get that from a `LabeledPoint`

** I haven't tested above code so it can contain some errors.

Comment: great! really helped. I'll make a try based on this codes! :)